# How import a function from another view with Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-import, django-import-export

I have this folder hierarchy:

```
|---- saga
    |---- core
         |---- views.py
    |---- study_time
         |---- views.py
```

On my `study_time/views.py`, I have this functions:

```
def study_time(request):
    def tasks_subjects(week_day, key):
        #Code here
        return __tasks

    def day_studies(week_day):
        __tasks_subjects = tasks_subjects(week_day, 0)
        #Code here
        return __studies

    return render(request, 'study_time.html', context)
```

On my `core/views.py`, I need the **day_studies()** function, so I'm importing like this:

```
from saga.study_time.views import day_studies
    def home(request):
        day_progress = day_studies(datetime.date.today().isoweekday())
```

But I'm getting the error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'day_studies'

How can I make this importation? I don't want to reply all code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've defined a nested function. That simply isn't visible outside the containing function; in fact, making it invisible from outside is pretty much the only good reason for defining nested functions in Python. Don't do that; move it outside the `study_time` function.

(Also, don't use double-underscore prefixes like that. They don't make any sense outside a class; and even there you should rarely if ever use them.)

Comment: I did that, but it wasn't working too, so I asked here. I did it again and saw that the problem was with the identation, my bad. About the double underscore, I'm not using like thid, it was just for a moment, when I was o arranging the variables, now it's all ok. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The inner function is not accessible,because it is local code for that function only. It is not generic for all in the views.py . So make a distinction on this.

Go through this for better understanding!!
https://realpython.com/blog/python/inner-functions-what-are-they-good-for/

Happy coding!!