# How to import python function from another file into django views

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to call a function from a python file that is located outside the django project directory from views.py. I have tried importing the python file but running the django server says "no module named xxxx".

Tree structure is given below.

```
├── auto_flash
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test.py
└── fireflash
    ├── detection_reports
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── admin.pyc
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __init__.pyc
    │   ├── migrations
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   └── __init__.pyc
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── models.pyc
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   └── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
    │   ├── templates
    │   │   └── detection_reports
    │   │       └── home.html
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   ├── views.py
    │   └── views.pyc
    ├── fireflash
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __init__.pyc
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
    │   │   └── settings.cpython-35.pyc
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── settings.pyc
    │   ├── ui_cgi.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   ├── urls.pyc
    │   ├── wsgi.py
    │   └── wsgi.pyc
    ├── __init__.py
    └── manage.py
```

Project name here is "fireflash" and there is an app in that project named "detection_reports". There is another directory named "auto_flash" that has same location as "fireflash". What I want to do is to import test.py file from "auto_flash" in detection_reports.views and call a function from views. Importing like this "from auto_flash import test" throws error "no module named auto_flash".

Comment: Can you provide a "file tree" with the relevant files (and their directories)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How import a function from another view with Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676426/how-import-a-function-from-another-view-with-django)

Comment: A similar question was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36622183/how-to-import-a-function-from-parent-folder-in-python)

Comment: I have tried the solutions suggested above but none of them worked. Anyone with clean/proper solution.?

Answer (score 0):

- Move `auto_flash` to `fireflash`
- In `detection_reports` add `from auto_flash import test.py`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all of the above mentioned solutions, but the cleaner solution was to append the path for `auto_flash` to `syspath` and the issue was resolved. Thanks to all of you for the efforts.